# Redirect queries to a specific server based on the collection (sharding?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two mongodb servers. Would it be possible to specify, based on the collection, on which server the query will be performed?

Preferably, I would like to do this at the application level (Rails + mongoid)

The reason is that I'm migrating some data and have this specific collection that will need to live temporary on a different server on the same vpc.

Thanks

Comment: So you will have a single model with collections on two different servers? Right. Is there any criteria in which this split between two servers happen. Like for example collections of a users which which start with `A` on one server and collections of user who start with `B` on the next.

Comment: @Coderhs no criteria. All the data for CollectionX will be on server 2, and all the data for all the other collections will be on server 1.  Thanks